# How to prove convergent sequences by definition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For this proof, I'm having trouble minimizing the denominator. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let $a_n = \frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}$. By definition, prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges. Make sure to fully justify your work.

Suppose $n>N$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.

$\lim{n \to \infty} \frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)} = 0$

$\frac{2-2n}{n^4-3n^2+n^3-3n}$

$\le \frac{2-2n}{n^3-3n}$

$ = \frac{2(1-n)}{n(n^2-3)}$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, fix some $0< \eta <1$, 
$$
|a_n|
= \left|\frac{2-2n}{(n^2+n)(n^2-3)}\right|
\overset{(*)}{<} \frac{2|1-n|}{(n^2+0)(n^2-\eta n^2)}
< \frac{2n}{n^4(1-\eta)} = \frac{2}{1-\eta} \cdot \frac{1}{n^3}
$$

where we use $n^2-3>n^2-\eta n^2$ at $(*)$ which holds for $n>\sqrt{\frac{3}{\eta}}$. Now we want $$\frac{2}{1-\eta} \frac{1}{n^3} < \epsilon,\quad \text{so require}\quad n >\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon(1-\eta)}}$$

Hence if $n > \max\left\{\sqrt{\frac{3}{\eta}},\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon(1-\eta)}}\right\}$ then $|a_n|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq 3$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{2-2n}{(n^{2}+n)(n^{2}-3)}\right|&\leq\dfrac{2+2n}{(n+n)(n^{2}-(1/2)n^{2})}\\
&=\dfrac{2(n+1)}{2n(1/2)n^{2}}\\
&=2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{4}{n^{2}},
\end{align*}
and $4/n^{2}<\epsilon$ for all large $n$.

Comment: Why are we assuming $n \ge 3$?

Comment: Then $n^{2}-(1/2)n^{2}\geq 0$.

Comment: How did we get to that step? I'm a little confused on how you got to your answer

Comment: $1/n\leq 1$ so $(1+1/n)\leq 2$.

Comment: $\leq\dfrac{2+2n}{(n+n)(n^{2}-(1/2)n^{2})}\\$ I mean how did you get to that step?

Comment: $n^{2}+n\geq n+n$, so flipping over, $1/(n^{2}+n)\leq 1/(n+n)$. And $(1/2)n^{2}\geq 3$ for $n\geq 3$, and so $n^{2}-3\geq n^{2}-(1/2)n^{2}$, flipping over, $1/(n^{2}-3)\leq 1/(n^{2}-(1/2)n^{2})$.

Comment: Where did n+n come from? Which factor did it come from?

Comment: I already told you, because $n^{2}+n\geq n+n$, then $1/(n^{2}+n)\leq 1/(n+n)$. We have $|2-2n|/(n^{2}+n)(n^{2}-3)=(1/(n^{2}+n))(|2-2n|/(n^{2}-3))$.

Comment: I understand everything afterwards. I just don't get where n+n came from.

Comment: First of all do you agree that $n^{2}+n\geq n+n$ will imply that $1/(n^{2}+n)\leq 1/(n+n)$? And do you see that there is a factor in your expression that $1/(n^{2}+n)$?

Comment: $\left|\dfrac{2-2n}{(n^{2}+n)(n^{2}-3)}\right|=\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+n}\cdot\dfrac{|2-2n|}{n^{2}-3}$, this is the simplest way to see that.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense now.